# Triple DES decryption invalid key with 16 bytes

Tags: java, android, encryption, tripledes

I have an android project in which am getting an Triple DES encrypted piece of text from my web services.  I need to Triple DES decrypt.

However, I am getting invalid key exceptions.  My key is converted to HEX format and I got an error: `W/System.err﹕ java.security.InvalidKeyException: DES key too long - should be 8 bytes` I found [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1528631) a forum explaining that hex may cause issue

*"DES keys are 56 bits normally packaged in 8 bytes so the chances are that the 16 bytes/characters they have given you are the hex encoded bytes of the key. You can get a hex decoder"*

So I converted my hex string to a byte array using

```
 private static byte[] hexStringtoByteArray(String hex){
        int len = hex.length();

        byte [] data = new byte[len/2];
        for(int i=0; i<len;i+=2){
            data[i/2] = (byte)((Character.digit(hex.charAt(i), 16)<<4) + Character.digit(hex.charAt(i+1),16));
        }
        return data;
    }
```

and passed that in to the cipher and I get an error:

```
W/System.err﹕ java.security.InvalidKeyException
W/System.err﹕ at javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec.
```

here is my decrypt method.  I would appreciate if someone could shine some light on where I might be going wrong.

```
 public String DesDecryptPin(String pin, String encryptKey) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF8";
    String decryptedPinText = null;

    byte[] hexConvert = hexStringtoByteArray(encryptKey);

    SecretKey desKey = null;
    KeySpec desKeySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(hexConvert); // Exception HERE
    Cipher desCipher;
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
    desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
    try {
        desKey = skf.generateSecret(desKeySpec);
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey);
    byte[] decryptPin = desCipher.doFinal(pin.getBytes());
    decryptedPinText = new String(decryptPin, "UTF-8");

    return decryptedPinText;
}
```

My key is C9AF269DF8A78A06D1216BFFF8F0536A.

*I have checked with the client and the key is correct, so the same key is being used for encryption.*

***Encryption Code***

```
 public string TripleDESEncrypt(string strClearText, string strKey)
    {
        byte[] bytClearText;
        byte[] bytClearTextChunk = new byte[8];
        byte[] bytEncryptedChunk = new byte[8];
        int BytesCount = 0;
        int nArrayPosition = 0;
        string strEncryptedChar;
        string strEncryptedText = "";

        ArrayList Input = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList Output = new ArrayList();

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider)TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider.Create();

        tdes.Key = HexToByteArray(strKey);
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

        ICryptoTransform tdesEncrypt = tdes.CreateEncryptor();

        bytClearText = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strClearText);
        BytesCount = bytClearText.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < BytesCount; i++)
        {
            if (nArrayPosition == 8)
            {
                Input.Add(bytClearTextChunk);
                bytClearTextChunk = new byte[8];
                nArrayPosition = 0;
            }
            bytClearTextChunk[nArrayPosition] = bytClearText[i];
            nArrayPosition++;
        }

        if (nArrayPosition != 0)
            Input.Add(bytClearTextChunk);


        foreach (byte[] Cbyte in Input)
        {
            tdesEncrypt.TransformBlock(Cbyte, 0, 8, bytEncryptedChunk, 0);
            Output.Add(bytEncryptedChunk);
            bytEncryptedChunk = null;
            bytEncryptedChunk = new byte[8];
        }


        foreach (byte[] Cbyte in Output)
        {
            foreach (byte BByte in Cbyte)
            {
                strEncryptedChar = BByte.ToString("X");
                strEncryptedChar = strEncryptedChar.PadLeft(2, Convert.ToChar("0"));
                strEncryptedText += strEncryptedChar;
            }
        }

        return strEncryptedText;
    }
```

Here is an example of the decrypted text with 14 chars: 12345678901234

Comment: Well how long is it and what character sets are used? Without any information about the key, this is just a [guessing game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/). I [don't like](http://i1.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/011/365/Grumpy-Cat.jpg) games.

Comment: C9AF269DF8A78A06D1216BFFF8F0536A is the key

Comment: Can't you add this to your question? Btw, what is the line where the error is thrown?

Comment: @ArtjomB.      `W/System.err﹕ java.security.InvalidKeyException W/System.err﹕ at javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec.` error is thrown at the line `KeySpec desKeySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(hexConvert);`

Answer (score 5):

DES would expect an 8 byte key (with parity). So Triple DES expects a 24 byte key (with parity). Since you only have a 16 byte key, you have to replicate some of it, to get the final key. Oftentimes the first and last 8 bytes are the same. You can try two variants:

```
byte[] tdesKey = new byte[24];
System.arraycopy(hexConvert, 0, tdesKey, 0, 16);
System.arraycopy(hexConvert, 0, tdesKey, 16, 8);
// tdesKey := K1 || K2 || K1
```

or

```
byte[] tdesKey = new byte[24];
System.arraycopy(hexConvert, 8, tdesKey, 0, 8);
System.arraycopy(hexConvert, 0, tdesKey, 8, 16);
// tdesKey := K2 || K1 || K2
```

when

```
hexConvert := K1 || K2
```

Comment: @Arjom B.        When I use these I get a return from the method, however, my decrypted text is ﹕ ��0�8��/0��<y� [H�zB���N&lP  I'm just wondering that the reason for that is

Comment: I don't know. I'm still guessing. Post the code that encrypted this. Show what it was supposed to be decrypted to.

Comment: @Arjom B.  apologies, I have managed to get the encrypt code, this is done server side, on the clients server. I'll edit the original post to include the server side code..it's done in c#  -- I have posted that

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the C# crypto API, so I can't help you there, but it looks correct. Also, I can't test it, because I don't have it installed.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure what it is I can do...So even though you're not familiar with the api the encryption and decryption look correct?   I'm trying to test the c# with this online compiler  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_csharp_online.php

Comment: I've compile the c# in that online compile and it works perfectly..I'm now trying to compile the java decrypt

Comment: Thanks for the hint of repeating the key to get 24 bytes: this worked for me.
The implementation I am working with is Microsoft C# using System.Security.Cryptography.
The TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider gets a key passed in of only 16 bytes and it automagically extends it out to 24 bytes by repeating the key.
I tested this using: CyberChef https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/ (the only catch was decoding the text from UTF16LE).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you must to use this cipher:

```
public byte[] encTripleDes (String txt, byte [] key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeySpecException{
    DESedeKeySpec keySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(key);
    SecretKeyFactory keyfactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
    SecretKey ky = keyfactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, ky);
    return cipher.doFinal(txt.getBytes("UTF-8"));

}
```

And for decrypting:

```
public byte[] uncTripleDes (byte [] encryptedTextBytes, byte [] key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeySpecException{
    DESedeKeySpec keySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(key);
    SecretKeyFactory keyfactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
    SecretKey ky = keyfactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, ky);
    return cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextBytes);

}
```

Look that I use a "PKCS5Padding" in the instance of the cipher.

Notice that the padding is used for give the same size at all the blocks (for example if the last block is 788 instead of 1024).

For create the key, in my solution (it's not the only one), I calculate a sha-256 hash and then I get the necessary bytes for the Des key:

Calculating the hash:

```
public byte[] sumCalc (){ 
    String key = "anyKey";
    byte[] hashedKey = null;
    try {
        byte [] byteKey = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        hashedKey = md.digest(byteKey);
    }catch (Exception ex){
        System.err.println("Error generant clau" + ex);  
    }
    return hashedKey;
}
```

Finally get only the 128 bytes that we need for the Des key:

```
bytedKey = Arrays.copyOf(bytedKey, 16 ); // 16 use only first 128 bit. if 32 use only 256
```

It's my solution but not the only one!

Comment: thank you for that,there is great info there, however, I don't do the encryption and there is an issue with the key.

Answer (score 0):

You instantiate your Cipher as a (singel) DES Cipher with:

```
desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
```

But your key is a **16 byte** 3Des key, and thuse you get the error

```
DES key too long - should be 8 bytes
```

Try instantiating your cipher as a 3DES cipher with:

```
desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/NoPadding");
```

Comment: i get this Exception "ECB mode does not use an IV"