# Triple DES Encrypt C# - Decrypt in Java

Tags: java, c#, encryption, tripledes

I'm getting a Triple DES decrypted string from the clients server, which has been coded in c# (see below):

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

    var encryption = TripleDESEncrypt("12345678901234", "C9AF269DF8A78A06D1216BFFF8F0536A");
      Console.WriteLine(encryption);

    }

      public static string TripleDESEncrypt(string strClearText, string strKey)
        {
            byte[] bytClearText;
            byte[] bytClearTextChunk = new byte[8];
            byte[] bytEncryptedChunk = new byte[8];
            int BytesCount = 0;
            int nArrayPosition = 0;
            string strEncryptedChar;
            string strEncryptedText = "";

            ArrayList Input = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList Output = new ArrayList();

            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider)TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider.Create();

            tdes.Key = HexToByteArray(strKey);
            tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

            ICryptoTransform tdesEncrypt = tdes.CreateEncryptor();

            bytClearText = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strClearText);
            BytesCount = bytClearText.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < BytesCount; i++)
            {
                if (nArrayPosition == 8)
                {
                    Input.Add(bytClearTextChunk);
                    bytClearTextChunk = new byte[8];
                    nArrayPosition = 0;
                }
                bytClearTextChunk[nArrayPosition] = bytClearText[i];
                nArrayPosition++;
            }

            if (nArrayPosition != 0)
                Input.Add(bytClearTextChunk);


            foreach (byte[] Cbyte in Input)
            {
                tdesEncrypt.TransformBlock(Cbyte, 0, 8, bytEncryptedChunk, 0);
                Output.Add(bytEncryptedChunk);
                bytEncryptedChunk = null;
                bytEncryptedChunk = new byte[8];
            }


            foreach (byte[] Cbyte in Output)
            {
                foreach (byte BByte in Cbyte)
                {
                    strEncryptedChar = BByte.ToString("X");
                    strEncryptedChar = strEncryptedChar.PadLeft(2, Convert.ToChar("0"));
                    strEncryptedText += strEncryptedChar;
                }
            }

            return strEncryptedText;
        }
        private static byte[] HexToByteArray(string strHex)
        {
            byte[] bytArray = new byte[strHex.Length / 2];
            int positionCount = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < strHex.Length; i += 2)
            {
                bytArray[positionCount] = byte.Parse(strHex.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                positionCount++;
            }
            return bytArray;
        }
}
```

I am then trying to Triple DES decrypt it in Java using this key: `C9AF269DF8A78A06D1216BFFF8F0536A`

Here is my code to decrypt:

```
public String DesDecryptPin(String pin, String encryptKey) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF8";
        String decryptedPinText = null;

        byte[] hexConvert = hexStringtoByteArray(encryptKey);

        SecretKey desKey = null;
        byte[] tdesKey = new byte[24];
        System.arraycopy(hexConvert, 0, tdesKey, 0,16);
        System.arraycopy(hexConvert, 0, tdesKey, 0,8);

        byte[] encryptKeyBytes = encryptKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);

        KeySpec desKeySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(tdesKey);
        Cipher desCipher;
        SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
        desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/NoPadding");
        try {
            desKey = skf.generateSecret(desKeySpec);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey);

       byte[] decryptPin = desCipher.doFinal(pin.getBytes());
        decryptedPinText = new String(decryptPin, "UTF-8");
        return decryptedPinText;
    }
```

The sample out put would be input/output would be `"12345678901234"`  however, I'm getting jumbled nonsense returned e.g ��0�8��/0��

So something is getting lost between c# and java...
This is a follow on from a previous question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671427/triple-des-decryption-invalid-key-with-16-bytes/29672530?noredirect=1#comment47492235_29672530)

I'd appreciate help on this

***changes to code***

```
   public String DesDecryptPin(String pin, String encryptKey) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF8";
        String decryptedPinText = null;



        SecretKey desKey = null;
        byte[] encryptKeyBytes = EncodingUtils.getAsciiBytes(encryptKey);
        byte[] tdesKey = new byte[24];
        System.arraycopy(encryptKeyBytes, 8, tdesKey, 0, 8);
        System.arraycopy(encryptKeyBytes, 0, tdesKey, 8, 16);
        KeySpec desKeySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(tdesKey);
        Cipher desCipher;
        SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
        desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/NoPadding");
        try {
            desKey = skf.generateSecret(desKeySpec);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey);

        byte[] decryptPin = desCipher.doFinal(EncodingUtils.getAsciiBytes(pin));

        decryptedPinText = new String(decryptPin, "ASCII");
        return decryptedPinText;
    }
```

***c# decrypt code***

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

        var encryption = TripleDESDecrypt("1D30CC3DE1641D7F5E821D13FC1200C3", "C9AF269DF8A78A06D1216BFFF8F0536A");
        Console.WriteLine(encryption);

    }

      public static string TripleDESDecrypt(string strEncryptedText, string strKey)
        {
            string errorMessage = "";
            int errorCode = 0;
            string strDecryptedText = "";

            try
            {
                byte[] bytEncryptedChunk = new byte[8];
                byte[] bytClearTextChunk = new byte[8];
                byte[] _bytesEmpty = new byte[8];
                int BytesCount = 0;
                int positionCount = 0;


                ArrayList Input = new ArrayList();
                ArrayList Output = new ArrayList();

                TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider)TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider.Create();

                tdes.Key = HexToByteArray(strKey);
                tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

                ICryptoTransform tdesDecrypt = tdes.CreateDecryptor();

                BytesCount = strEncryptedText.Length;

                for (int i = 0; i < BytesCount; i += 2)
                {
                    if (positionCount == 8)
                    {
                        positionCount = 0;
                        Input.Add(bytEncryptedChunk);
                        bytEncryptedChunk = new byte[8];
                    }

                    bytEncryptedChunk[positionCount] = byte.Parse(strEncryptedText.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                    positionCount++;
                }

                if (positionCount != 0)
                {
                    Input.Add(bytEncryptedChunk);
                }

                foreach (byte[] Cbyte in Input)
                {
                    tdesDecrypt.TransformBlock(Cbyte, 0, 8, _bytesEmpty, 0);
                    tdesDecrypt.TransformBlock(Cbyte, 0, 8, bytClearTextChunk, 0);
                    Output.Add(bytClearTextChunk);
                    bytClearTextChunk = null;
                    bytClearTextChunk = new byte[8];
                }

                foreach (byte[] Cbyte in Output)
                {
                    strDecryptedText += ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(Cbyte);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorCode = 1;
                errorMessage = ex.Message;


            }
Console.WriteLine(strDecryptedText);
            return strDecryptedText;
        }

        private static byte[] HexToByteArray(string strHex)
        {
            byte[] bytArray = new byte[strHex.Length / 2];
            int positionCount = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < strHex.Length; i += 2)
            {
                bytArray[positionCount] = byte.Parse(strHex.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                positionCount++;
            }
            return bytArray;
        }
}
```

This returns what is inputting into the encrypt 12345678901234

Comment: Did you try decrypting with PKCS5Padding padding, like the answerer of your other question suggested???

Comment: @Barett  There is no padding added in the encryption, I'm not that familiar but I didn't think I should add padding to decryption if there isn't padding in encryption

Comment: Have you tested each part independently? Trying the C# side produced an encryption string of `1D30CC3DE1641D7F5E821D13FC1200C3` where an online tool says it should be `c8 2b 53 b6 c1 ef bb 23 84 12 dd 6d 2f de 6a 4a `

Comment: I've tried those tools too http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/ gives me xTRqxlMmkakJZBrHF8dPHw==   So I'm not sure what is going on.  I do know that this works as it is also a windows app and the decryption in c# is correct.  Also just to be aware are different hex types

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765651/c-sharp-to-java-tripledes-different-results?noredirect=1#comment80671439_33765651

Comment: @DJ-DOO did you ever menage to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

In your C# code, you use ASCII:

```
bytClearText = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strClearText);
```

While in Java you use UNICODE:

```
byte[] encryptKeyBytes = encryptKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
```

Try to change your C# to use UNICODE or your java code to use ASCII.

Also, since the C# is padding the output :

```
strEncryptedChar = strEncryptedChar.PadLeft(2, Convert.ToChar("0"));
```

You probably must check to remove all the '00' in the crypted string, so 1D30CC3DE1641D7F5E821D13FC12**00**C3 will become 1D30CC3DE1641D7F5E821D13FC12C3

(you must check if it's in the boundaries of an hex expression: 1C01A1 should probably be  modified since it got a padding on the second Hexa 1C **0**1 A1: 1C1A1

Comment: Thanks for your response...the c# code is not in my control, however, I'm not actually using the encryptedBytes byte []

Comment: so I swapped out ` byte[] encryptKeyBytes = encryptKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);` for `EncodingUtils.getAsciiBytes(encryptKey);` and used the encryptedKeyBytes, unfortunately it's still jumbled rubbish

Comment: Have you also changed decryptedPinText = new String(decryptPin, "UTF-8"); to decryptedPinText = new String(decryptPin, "ASCII");

Comment: I can provide the c# decryption if that helps?

Comment: What's the C# encrypted string ? is it 1D30CC3DE1641D7F5E821D13FC1200C3 ?

Comment: The think that's bother me is this line 'strEncryptedChar = strEncryptedChar.PadLeft(2, Convert.ToChar("0"));' in c#. If you try to descript 1D30CC3DE1641D7F5E821D13FC12C3 is it working ?

Comment: just working on that now...trying in online compiler

Comment: yep, it returns 12345678901234  I've included the c# decrypt above

Comment: All I've done is to remove 00 from the crypted string. Try with other string and seed if it's always working. And if you want you can accept my answer.

Comment: sorry, what 00 did you remove?  Can you expand your answer above?  I'll be back on line and test and if it works, I'll accept

Comment: I tested with another string "This is a string for encryption" and it worked encrypted and decrypted correctly.  Can you explain what you mean by removing '00' from the crypted string?  which '00'?

Comment: hi, thanks for that.  Unfortunately this isn't the case for each.  There are no '00' within "This is a string for encryption" when encrypted.  Thanks anyway

Comment: No, I'm afraid not, here is the encrypted hex of the above string     CD8DAAFEC6D78779E30A25D1FC7CC39988189796FA2FDAC7DAD3F2FB7FC495AD

Comment: Yes there is: 0A (...E30A25 ...)

Comment: apologies, I don't understand.  If I remove anything from the encrypted string I get this error when I try to decrypt  `javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: error:0606508A:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length`

Answer (score 0):

acording https://stackoverflow.com/a/33768305/1140304 you can use
unicode instead of UTF-8 in java code

> encrypt in c# :

```
public static string Encrypt2(string clearText,string key)
{
    try
    {
        string encryptedText = "";
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        TripleDES des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        des.KeySize = 128;
        des.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        des.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        byte[] md5Bytes = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key));

        byte[] ivBytes = new byte[8];


        des.Key = md5Bytes;

        des.IV = ivBytes;

        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);

        ICryptoTransform ct = des.CreateEncryptor();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            encryptedText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
        return encryptedText;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

> for decode in c# you can use:

```
public static string Decrypt2(string cipher,string key)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] clearBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipher);
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] md5Bytes = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key));
        string encryptedText = "";
        TripleDES des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        des.KeySize = 128;
        des.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        des.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        byte[] ivBytes = new byte[8];
        des.Key = md5Bytes;
        des.IV = ivBytes;
        ICryptoTransform ct = des.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = ct.TransformFinalBlock(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
        encryptedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(resultArray);
        return encryptedText;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

> now, for encrypt in java you can use :

```
private String _encrypt2(String clearText,String key )
{
    try
    {
        /**
         * create md5
         */
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
        byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(key.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
        byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
        for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8; )
        {
            keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
        }


        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, 0, 24, "DESede");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, iv);

        byte[] plainTextBytes = clearText.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);

        String output = Base64.encodeToString(cipherText,Base64.DEFAULT);
        return output;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {}
    return "";
}
```

> and for decrypt in java :

```
private String _decrypt2(String encryptText,String key)
{

    MessageDigest md = null;
    byte[] digestOfPassword = null;

    try
    {
        byte[] message = Base64.decode(encryptText.getBytes("UTF-16LE"), Base64.DEFAULT);

        /**
         * make md5
         */
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
        digestOfPassword = md.digest(key.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
        byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
        for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8; )
        {
            keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
        }

        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, 0, 24, "DESede");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, iv);
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(message);

        return new String(cipherText, "UTF-16LE");
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InvalidKeyException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (NoSuchPaddingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (BadPaddingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone find himself/herself in the same problem like I did, here is a java implementation (android) of the same .NET decrypt function:

```
 public static byte[] byteArrayConcat(byte[] array1, byte[] array2) {
        byte[] result = new byte[array1.length + array2.length];
        System.arraycopy(array1, 0, result, 0, array1.length);
        System.arraycopy(array2, 0, result, array1.length, array2.length);
        return result;
    }


 private byte[] fGPKeyTo3DESKey(byte[] GPKey) {

        byte[] _3DESKey = new byte[24];
        byte[] tmp = new byte[8];

        arraycopy(GPKey, 0, tmp, 0, 8);

        _3DESKey = DaPlugUtils.byteArrayConcat(GPKey, tmp);

        return _3DESKey;
    }
```

```
 private static byte[] hexStringtoByteArray(String hex) {
        int len = hex.length();

        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hex.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(hex.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }
```

```
public String desDecryptPin(String pin, String encryptKey) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeySpecException {

        int bytesCount = 0;
        int positionCount = 0;


        byte[] bytEncryptedChunk = new byte[8];

        ArrayList<byte[]> Input = new ArrayList();
        bytesCount = pin.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < bytesCount; i += 2) {
            if (positionCount == 8) {
                positionCount = 0;
                Input.add(bytEncryptedChunk);
                bytEncryptedChunk = new byte[8];
            }
            bytEncryptedChunk[positionCount] = (byte) (Integer.parseInt(pin.substring(i, i + 2), 16));
            positionCount++;
        }

        if (positionCount != 0) {
            Input.add(bytEncryptedChunk);
        }


        byte[] _3DESKey = fGPKeyTo3DESKey(hexStringtoByteArray(encryptKey));

        DESedeKeySpec keySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(_3DESKey);
        SecretKey k = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede").generateSecret(keySpec);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k);


        String res = "";

        for (byte[] bs : Input) {
            byte[] decryptPin = cipher.doFinal(bs);
            String a = new String(decryptPin, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

            res += a;
        }

        return res.trim();
    }
```