# Android encrypt 3DES ECB

Tags: android, security, encryption, 3des

I need to encrypt some data with a custom key generated from a passphrase.

It MUST be:
3DES
Cipher Mode: ECB
Padding Mode: Zeros

I can't find any code to do that. Can anyone show me an example?

I've tried this and it show me the following error

```
ERROR: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: expected IV length of 0


import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Encryption {

public static int MAX_KEY_LENGTH = DESedeKeySpec.DES_EDE_KEY_LEN;
private static String ENCRYPTION_KEY_TYPE = "DESede";
private static String ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM = "DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding";
private final SecretKeySpec keySpec;

public Encryption(String passphrase) {
    byte[] key;
    try {
        // get bytes representation of the password
        key = passphrase.getBytes("UTF8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }

    key = padKeyToLength(key, MAX_KEY_LENGTH);
    keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, ENCRYPTION_KEY_TYPE);
}

// !!! - see post below
private byte[] padKeyToLength(byte[] key, int len) {
    byte[] newKey = new byte[len];
    System.arraycopy(key, 0, newKey, 0, Math.min(key.length, len));
    return newKey;
}

// standard stuff
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] unencrypted) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    return doCipher(unencrypted, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
}

public byte[] decrypt(byte[] encrypted) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    return doCipher(encrypted, Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
}

private byte[] doCipher(byte[] original, int mode) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
    // IV = 0 is yet another issue, we'll ignore it here
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
    cipher.init(mode, keySpec, iv);
    return cipher.doFinal(original);
}
}
```

EDITED:
Now I have this, and I pass as "passphrase" parameter my custom key (key size=8)
The php I call is not accepting the encrypted result (it's not correct).

The correct encryption is the one this web does putting Algorith "tripledes" and mode: ECB
https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/

I don't know yet what I am doing wrong...

```
public class Encryption {

public static int MAX_KEY_LENGTH = DESedeKeySpec.DES_EDE_KEY_LEN;
private static String ENCRYPTION_KEY_TYPE = "DESede";
private static String ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM = "DESede/ECB/NoPadding";
private final SecretKeySpec keySpec; 

public Encryption(String passphrase) {
        byte[] key;
    try {
        // get bytes representation of the password
        key = passphrase.getBytes("UTF8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }

    key = padKeyToLength(key, MAX_KEY_LENGTH);
    keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, ENCRYPTION_KEY_TYPE);
}


private byte[] padKeyToLength(byte[] key, int len) {
    byte[] newKey = new byte[len];
    System.arraycopy(key, 0, newKey, 0, Math.min(key.length, len));
    return newKey;
}

// standard stuff
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] unencrypted) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    return doCipher(unencrypted, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
}

public byte[] decrypt(byte[] encrypted) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    return doCipher(encrypted, Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
}

private byte[] doCipher(byte[] original, int mode) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
    int bs = cipher.getBlockSize();
    byte[] padded = new byte[original.length + bs - original.length % bs];
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, padded, 0, original.length);
    cipher.init(mode, keySpec);
    return cipher.doFinal(padded);
}
```

Comment: You just posted the key you're using for encryption on the internet...

Comment: The error is pretty clear: "expected IV length of 0". ECB mode doesn't use an IV, but you really shouldn't use ECB. It's not semantically secure. Use at the very least CBC mode with a random IV for every encryption. The IV doesn't have to be secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext, but it has to be unpredictable.

Comment: @Relequestual the key I posted it's a sample, it was not the real key. I don't know why someone has downvoted the question.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I have to use ECB because I have to call a php that needs data encrypted in 3DES.

Comment: Fair enough. Related to your other comment. Do you have no control over the system you're calling?

Comment: @Relequestual No, I have not, that's the problem. I must do it that way.

Comment: I would add that to your question to avoid more suggestings of using an alternative. While they may seem constrcutive, you don't always have an option. Of course the question is raised them if you should actually be interacting with the other system at all, consdiering.

Answer (score 0):

ECB mode doesn't use an IV which makes it a deterministic cipher mode which means that it is not semantically secure. If you still need to use it, remove the IV as a parameter:

```
int bs = cipher.getBlockSize();
byte[] padded = new byte[original.length + bs - original.length % bs];
System.arraycopy(original, 0, padded, 0, original.length);
cipher.init(mode, keySpec);
return cipher.doFinal(padded);
```

This will give you a zero padded message that can then be encrypted. This works, because a byte array is always initialized with zeros in them. The padding is the same as BouncyCastle's ZeroPadding. If you want to do zero padding as PHP's mcrypt does it, then use

```
byte[] padded = new byte[original.length + (bs - original.length % bs) % bs];
```

Comment: Ok, now it works, but it't not encrypting like it should be, I think the problem is in the padding, I can't put ZeroPading because it says it doesn't exist, but It MUST be ZeroPading.

Comment: Edited my question with actual code. Not final solution yet. Do you know what's wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing wrong. Personally, I really dislike matching encryption code to some online tool that doesn't specify how they are encryption stuff. There are a million things that can be done differently. You're on your own.

Comment: The web says this "This tool uses the mcrypt_encrypt() function in PHP"
Thanks for your help

Comment: Still, there is a lot that can be done [differently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31734468/1816580). In particular, TDEA/3DES has different layouts of subkeys (remember it is EDE and each of those three phases should have it's own 64 bit key). I suspect this could have something to do with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29672530/1816580), but it would be just [guessing](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) and I don't like to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here's example of code I use to encrypt something with 3DES. I also use Base64 for my secretKey, but I think you'll figure this out.

```
public class KeywordsCipher {

private static final String PADDING = "DESede/ECB/NoPadding";
private static final String UTF_F8 = "UTF-8";
private static final String DE_SEDE = "DESede";
private String secretKey;

{...}

public String encrypt(String message, String secretKey) {

    byte[] cipherText = null;

    try {
        final byte[] secretBase64Key = Base64.decodeBase64(secretKey);
        final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(secretBase64Key, DE_SEDE);
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(PADDING);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        final byte[] plainTextBytes = message.getBytes();
        cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        throw new CipherException("Problem with encryption occured");
    }

    return Hex.encodeHexString(cipherText);
}

public CipherKeywordModel decrypt(String keyToDecrypt, String secretKey) {

    try {
        byte[] message = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(keyToDecrypt);
        final byte[] secretBase64Key = Base64.decodeBase64(secretKey);
        final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(secretBase64Key, DE_SEDE);
        final Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance(PADDING);
        decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        final byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(message);
        String decryptedText = new String(plainText, UTF_F8);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        throw new CipherException("Problem with encryption occured");
    }
    return decryptedText;
}
```

Comment: Can you show more code? What is CipherKeywordModel? How can I use the string key I need to use? What is DSLContext?

Comment: Hi, I edited this code, removing CipherKeywordModel and DSLContext. I used in to create some objects and using database, but you won't need this. This code now uses only secretKey. You might not want to use Base64 encoding of secret key. If so,use just  final byte[] secretBase64Key = secretKey.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));